# Java Generics function calling

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, nodes, generic-collections

I'm creating my own linklist data structure in java where each node in the linked list will hold an object of a another class (car class for eg).So it'll basically be a linked list of cars.

```
public class car {      
    private String carName;
    private double price;

    car(String name,double price){
        this.carName=name;
        this.price=price;   
    }           
    public int compareTo(car newCar)
    {
        return this.carName.compareTo(newCar.carName);          
    }       
}
```

Now I am trying to make the link list generic so that it can also be a `Linklist` of integers,strings or other objects.

```
customLinklist<cars> newList=customLinklist<cars>()
customLinklist<String> newList=customLinklist<String>()
customLinklist<float> newList=customLinklist<float>()
```

The `LinkList` is sorted alphabetically so when I add a car to the list it'll be inserted in a sorted manner.

In the ADD function in the `Linklist` I compare the  objects(which are wrapped in the nodes) to find out the location where I have to add the new object/node

This is my CustomLinklist class and Node Class

```
public class CustomLinkedList<E> {

    public class Node<E>{   
        private E data;
        private Node<E> next;
        private Node<E> back;

        public int compareTo(Node<E> newNode){

            return this.data.compareTo(newNode.data);       
        }

    }


    private Node<E> head,tail;


    CustomLinkedList(){ 
        head=null;  
        tail=null;
    }


    public void add(E newObject){

        if (head==null)
        {
            head=new Node<E>();
            head.data=newObject;
            head.next=null;
            head.back=null;
            tail=head;

        }
        else
        {
            Node<E> currentNode=head,newNode = null;
            Node<E> prevNode;


            newNode=new Node<E>();
            newNode.data=newObject;
            newNode.next=null;
            newNode.back=null;


            while( currentNode.compareTo(newNode)<0 && currentNode.next!=null)
            {
                currentNode=currentNode.next;
            }           


            if(currentNode.next==null && currentNode!=head)
            {
                currentNode.next=newNode;
                newNode.back=currentNode;
                tail=newNode;

            }
            else
            {       
                prevNode=currentNode.back;
                if(currentNode!=head)
                {

                    prevNode.next=newNode;
                }
                newNode.back=prevNode;
                newNode.next=currentNode;
                currentNode.back=newNode;

                if(currentNode==head)
                {

                    head=newNode;

                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Now the comparison logic I want to keep in the object class( car class) so that any changes the made to be made in the future( if i want to compare prices for eg) will be made to the car class .

Since I'm trying to make it generic,so that I can use the `Linklists` to hold other objects( which will also have the compareTo function) ,this part of the code:

```
public int compareTo(Node<E> newNode){

            return this.data.compareTo(newNode.data);       
        }
```

does not allow call the `compareTo` function and gives the error "The method `compareTo(E)` is undefined for the type E"

How can I make it generic so that I can call the compare function without knowing  the type of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have to make sure that the elements in your linked list are comparable. You do that by using `Comparable` interface. So your linked list should only contain element that implement `Comparable` interface. How do you do that? By giving bound to your type parameter `E`:

```
class MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> { ... }
```

This means that, in order to add `Car` to your list, it has to implement `Comparable<Car>`.

Comment: Also, `class car implements Comparable<car>`

Answer (score 0):

Use type constraint as follows:

```
public class CustomLinkedList<E extends Comparable>
```

Thus you require that type **E** must have a *compareTo()* method. And each type **E** knows how to compare itself.